# Construct rotation matrix from angle variable in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

My goal is to generate a rotation matrix based on a rotation variable, theta.

Here's my code so far:

```
initial = 0.0
theta = tf.Variable(initial_value=initial, name='theta')
sin = tf.sin(theta)
cos = tf.cos(theta)
rot_matrix = tf.constant([[cos, -sin, 0], [sin, cos, 0]])
```

The above gives: `TypeError: List of Tensors when single Tensor expected` for the fifth line. I'm getting this because `cos` and `sin` are tensors. But I can't find any way to extract a value from a tensor. (Only extracting sub-tensors from tensors with tf.slice())

How can I properly create the rotation matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make it a list of tensors and fetch that. Right now you have a mix of tensors and numbers which you can not fetch as is.

```
initial = 0.0
theta = tf.Variable(initial_value=initial, name='theta')
sin = tf.sin(theta)
cos = tf.cos(theta)
rot_matrix = [[cos, -sin, tf.constant(0)], [sin, cos, tf.constant(0)]]
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
sess.run(rot_matrix)
```

Alternatively you could turn it into a single Tensor using `tf.pack()`, which converts numbers (and lists and arrays of numbers) to tensors automatically.

`rot_matrix = tf.pack([[cos, -sin, 0], [sin, cos, 0]])`